# javascript: call function inside object, from a callback function

Tags: javascript, object, callback

when i try to call a function inside the object using "this" from a callback function, an error occur saying that the method is undefined.
How can I solve this issue!.

```
 var object_log = {
    user: "",
    pass: "",
    error_message: "an error occured while connecting",
    init: function(user, pass) {
        this.user = user;
        this.pass = pass;
    },
    login: function() {
        remote_submit(identify, this.success, this.error);
    },
    error: function() {
        alert(this.error_message);
    },
    success: function() {
        alert("success");
    }
};
```

Comment: Where is `this.success` defined?

Comment: My code is too Long, that because I create an example. so sorry, let me edit it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `.call()` or `.apply()` methods on the callback to specify the context which the method is called upon.

The callback method `remote_submit` does not know what `this` will be anymore and thus when it calls the callback methods they're executed like normal functions not on an object.

You can "Bind" your functions by wrapping them on the way out:

```
var self = this;
remote_submit(
  identify,
  function() { return self.success.apply(self, arguments); },
  function() { return self.error.apply(self, arguments); }
);
```

This allows you to pass the context in the closure of the anonymous function and execute the callbacks with an exclusive `this` context.

It appears that in EMCAScript5+ you can use `bind` on the function to bind it for use in a callback:

```
remote_submit(identify, this.success.bind(), this.error.bind())
```

However from the [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

> The bind function is a recent addition to ECMA-262, 5th edition; as such it may not be present in all browsers. You can partially work around this by inserting the following code at the beginning of your scripts, allowing use of much of the functionality of bind() in implementations that do not natively support it.

The shim/polyfill is here:

```
if (!Function.prototype.bind) {
  Function.prototype.bind = function (oThis) {
    if (typeof this !== "function") {
      // closest thing possible to the ECMAScript 5 internal IsCallable function
      throw new TypeError("Function.prototype.bind - what is trying to be bound is not callable");
    }

    var aArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1), 
        fToBind = this, 
        fNOP = function () {},
        fBound = function () {
          return fToBind.apply(this instanceof fNOP && oThis
                                 ? this
                                 : oThis,
                               aArgs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
        };

    fNOP.prototype = this.prototype;
    fBound.prototype = new fNOP();

    return fBound;
  };
}
```

---

**Update**:

To answer your additional question, let's first look at the [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) documentation and break down how they work:

Fundamentally they work the same, the only difference is how they take their arguments:

```
myfunc.call(target, param1, param2, param3);
```

Will call `myfunc(param1, param2, param3)` with `target` as `this`.

```
var args = [param1, param2, param3];
myfunc.apply(target, args);
```

Will call `myfunc(param1, param2, param3)` with `target` as `this`.

Basically the difference is that `.apply()` takes an array of arguments, where the `call` function requires you to write in the arguments in the code.

Next, if we look at the example i gave you:

```
function() { return self.success.apply(self, arguments); }
```

This returns a function that will call your callback by passing all the arguments (`arguments` variable) that were passed into the anonymous function, onto the `apply` function. So:

```
var a = function() { return self.success.apply(self, arguments); };
a(1,2,3,4);
```

This will call `self.success(1,2,3,4)` with `self` as `this`. If you'd like to augment the arguments with something specific for example if you wanted `a(1,2,3,4)` to call `self.success(self.test, 1, 2, 3, 4)` then you'll have to provide an augmented array to the `apply` function:

```
var a = function() {
  var args = [self.test];
  for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) args[] = arguments[i];
  return self.success.apply(self, args);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you was very helpful.
another question please:does there are a way to send other data.
exp. something like this:function() { self.success.apply(self,"Hello", arguments); },

Answer (score 1):

When you pass the function as a callback, do it like this:

```
  whatever( object_log.login.bind( object_log ) );
```

That call to the `.bind` method will return a function that'll make sure your "login" function will be called such that `this` references the "object_log" object.

There's a good shim for `.bind` for older browsers [at the MDN documentation site.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility)

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but `bind` is only available in EMCASCript5 + which could be a problem depending on the browser, and that's likely the reason.

Comment: @Aren well it's available in all modern browsers, and there's a good shim - I'll add reference for that.

Comment: Unfortunately a lot of us are stuck supporting IE8, I gave you an upvote to counter the -1 because you are correct.